# How to detect if an element is visible within an iframe that is on a cross domain parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-domain, visibility

Just as the question states, I have an iframe that is on a cross domain parent. I need to trigger an event if that content is scrolled into view or already in view on page load. Normal checks for distance from top/side of page and viewport height/width don't seem to work as they measure the page within the iframe itself.

I cannot edit/add anything on the parent page to enable this functionality, everything must be within the iframe itself.

The reason behind this is to record whether content has ever had the chance to be viewed by the user or if it was loaded out of view and kept there.

There are companies who provide this service for advertising, but as far as finding out how it is actually done, well it seems to be one of the dark arts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Two examples of the companies I spoke of who offer this service.

1. View the first tick under (4)
   http://www.doubleverify.com/what-is-verification/
2. First thing they state they can do on the right hand side http://adxpose.com/home.page

Answer (score 5):

spider.io does this probably using browser timing attacks. there is a video on their page:

http://www.spider.io/viewability/

here is a nice report on how some browser timing attacks work: http://www.contextis.com/documents/2/Browser_Timing_Attacks.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link to the white paper. Very interesting.

Comment: link broken on spider.io

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is, *you can't*.

You have no way to access a cross-domain `iframe` (`DOM` or `window object`) with ECMAscript because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Hi jAndy, thanks for replying. I'm afraid I'm going to have to disagree though, as I said there are many companies (legitimate) that offer this service, and I just can't see that they are all making up the numbers on their reports.

Comment: @Vendrad: whatever technique is used in your example links where companys state what they can do, it is for sure not Javascript + cross-domain iframe. As I stated, you can't access it.

Comment: I have added references to such companies in my original question. obviously I'm unsure of how they are doing it but the reports they provide show actual figures for "in view" impressions so it looks unlikely that they are running a program which loads the pages the advertising is running on to "see" from that side and provide a likelyhood score or otherwise.

Comment: I did try to leave my question open by explaining what the end goal is and although I tagged it with "JavaScript" I made no reference within the question to it.

Comment: We could assume that it is possible to deduce it somehow instead of accessing the top.window object. The new window.requestAnimationFrame() could be useful to check if the iframe is actually visible but I don't think it works on iframes yet.
Also, I can recall Flash Player initing the SWFs only if they are actually visible. in that cae you could embed a small flash object, wait for it to be initialized and assume that your window is in the viewport. Not very reliable, but at least something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those examples are exclusively iframe based? Maybe they need to add some javascript to the parent Window.

If you really need this, and 100% accuracy is not needed, I would try some time based techniques on the assumption that most browser will optimize graphical work happening out of view.

Being realistic I don't think it would be possible to get good results with that techniques in a reasonable time or expecting a general robust cross-browser solution. It would be quite fun though.

Comment: They're not exclusively iframe based, but for the times when it isn't, setting up an event on view is pretty simple to implement. The companies definitely have some amount of capability to provide these statistics even if they are within iframes, however their technique, whatever it may be, is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

doubleverify and adxpose use "offline" techniques to determine if the ad was visible or not, it doesn't happen on the page view. If they did it through Javascript, all you would have to do is look at one of their pixels to see how it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "offline" techniques? Do you mean some sort of modelling technique? They provide log level data showing the viewability of each impression so this would suggest something happening on page view.

I haven't checked recently, but I do remember witnessing calls being made when something scrolls into view, suggesting there is an event driven script in place. Working through minified code to determine what is going on is possible but not preferable.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this stuff so I don't remember the details, but basically they go to the pages themselves to see if the ad is visible rather than trying to determine anything at the time of the ad view